# Prometheus Cloudwatch Exporter Config

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch

I have Prometheus CloudWatch Exporter setup and pointed to our prometheus instance. I'm working through building out a config but I can't seem to get all of my metrics to show up in Prometheus.

I currently have `aws_applicationelb_request_count_average` and `aws_ec2_network_packets_in_sum` working but nothing else..

This is my config:

```
  region: us-east-1

  metrics:
  - aws_namespace: AWS/ApplicationELB
    aws_metric_name: HealthyHostCount
    aws_dimensions: [AvailabilityZone, LoadBalancer]
    aws_statistics: [Average]

  - aws_namespace: AWS/ApplicationELB
    aws_metric_name: UnHealthyHostCount
    aws_dimensions: [AvailabilityZone, LoadBalancer]
    aws_statistics: [Average]

  - aws_namespace: AWS/ApplicationELB
    aws_metric_name: RequestCount
    aws_dimensions: [AvailabilityZone, LoadBalancer]
    aws_statistics: [Average]

  - aws_namespace: AWS/ApplicationELB
    aws_metric_name: HTTPCode_ELB_5XX_Count
    aws_dimensions: [LoadBalancer]
    aws_statistics: [Average]

  - aws_namespace: AWS/ApplicationELB
    aws_metric_name: RequestCountPerTarget
    aws_dimensions: [LoadBalancer, TargetGroup]
    aws_statistics: [Average]

  - aws_namespace: AWS/EC2
    aws_metric_name: NetworkPacketsIn
    aws_dimensions: [InstanceId]
    aws_statistics: [Maximum, Sum]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I was attempting to gather metrics from AWS namespaces that didn't have metrics available. Once I added metrics that were available data started showing up..

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate on what do you mean by

> but I can't seem to get all of my metrics to show up in Prometheus.

Did you check if the expected metrics show up in the output of `aws cloudwatch list-metrics --namespace AWS/ApplicationELB` and similarly for `AWS/EC2` and also with the `get-metric-statistics` command ? You could also try out [this exporter](https://github.com/asserts/aws-exporter). It uses a different CloudWatch API to reduce the AWS API invocation costs

Comment: your answer should be a comment to the question since it not resolve the problem

Comment: The answer to the question depends on the metric data. Without knowing what the data is one can't know what is the expected behaviour and for that what the configuration should look like. So I just suggested the steps to know what the AWS commands show and then the next steps can be identified from there. I am just getting started on SOF so don't have enough reputation to comment on the question directly. But thanks for pointing this out !

Comment: BTW,  Didn't notice it earlier, but it looks like OP's issue got resolved. Not sure if my response contributed in any way ;)